# People picker accepting anything when using ADFS as claim provider

Tags: people-picker

I know the are other questions similar to this one, but I haven't found one that is the same.

Here's the thing: I've successfully configured a web app in SharePoint to authenticate using ADFS. When I open the people picker, I can see my claims provider and the claim (Email Address). The problem is that I can search anything and the people picker will tell me that whatever I look for belongs to the claim provider.

For example: I have a user named steve.harris and the email steve.harris@mail.com. When I search in the people picker for 'steve', It will appear as if 'steve' was the e-mail. And I can even search for 'foo' and grant it permissions and people picker won't complain about 'foo' not existing anywhere.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Working as designed. :)

I discussed this at TechEd last year: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/OSP308 
(about 40 minutes in)

The fix is custom development.

Comment: As Paul says in his excellent video, once you enable claims in SharePoint, the People Picker is really a "claims expression editor"(tm), so when you type in the email address and select the email claim on left, you're telling SharePoint to let anyone in who has a email claim matching that string.  It's quite a different concept then user/group selecting in NTLM, but still uses the same GUI.