# I'm having the same problem with People Editor using ADFS as claim provider

Tags: claims, adfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [People picker accepting anything when using ADFS as claim provider](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26300/people-picker-accepting-anything-when-using-adfs-as-claim-provider)

I can enter anything, like blah-blah, in the People Editor field, and when I click on the check button, it gets accepted immediately. But on the same site, if I go to the Check Permissions, the same blah-blah is rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to previous question: [People picker accepting anything when using ADFS as claim provider](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26300/people-picker-accepting-anything-when-using-adfs-as-claim-provider?rq=1)